# AS3 button to load movie and replace current movie

Tags: actionscript-3, button, loader

I have an attractor swf with an invisible button covering it

When you click the invisible button I would like to load a new swf to **replace** the attractor

The following code does work but the new swf goes on top of the attractor

Any help would be appreciated

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,f);

var loader_mc : Loader = new Loader();
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("file-to-load.swf");

function f(e:Event){
loader_mc.load(urlRequest);
addChild(loader_mc);
}
```

Comment: This last item added through `addChild()` is always on top, try `addChildAt(loader_mc,0);`

Comment: Hi - That doesn't appear to be working? - i replaced addChild with your suggestion above and nothing is happening now?

Comment: How did you make your button "invisible"? `Button.visible = false`?

Comment: No i literally created a button with a hit only state (so that it's turquoise)

Comment: Show the code that displays the attractor so we can figure out the context of the two objects.   ALso, I'm confused as to what the attractor is.  Are you replacing it or layering something behind it?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the whole swf - the attractor.swf contains a simple animation with a button on top of it - the button is supposed to open a new animation which replaces the attractor